# Number of stars in Ambartsumian's Knot NGC 3561 Galaxy

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

Is there any information on what type of stars and how many are in Ambartsumian's Knot Galaxy? Is there an information source to refer to?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are u, g, r, i and z-band photometric measurements of the object, which with a distance estimate (easy, assuming the distance of NGC 3561) will give a reasonable estimate of its stellar mass, and the stellar population making up that mass. The measurements are listed on Simbad, for instance: https://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=Ambartsumian%27s+Knot&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit+id

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the response